# How to play video from Google Drive in SwiftUI project?

Tags: swift, swiftui, google-drive-api, uikit

I have a JSON file stored on a server that contains a list of lessons. Each lesson has a Google Drive link to a video. I'm currently building a SwiftUI video player, and I'm looking for assistance on how to play the video directly from the Google Drive link.

Here's an example of the Google Drive link format:
"https://drive.google.com/file/d/xxxxxxxxxxx/view?usp=share_link"

I'm seeking guidance on how to extract the video URL from the Google Drive link and play it using the SwiftUI video player.

When I'm trying to implement a simple player, it's not working. I've also tried to use direct link, like that: https://drive.google.com/uc?export=download&id=xxxxxxxx, it's not working either. There was also an old method from [here](https://github.com/zaidfadhil/GDSLink/blob/master/GDSLink/ViewController.swift), but it didn't work too. Is it even possible to stream and play in AVPlayer from Google Drive?

Any help would be appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I can suggest you an alternative solution which is to embed youtube in your SwiftUI app. For that you can utilize WebViewContainer to embed youtube video layer in you app. Here is a resource you may follow. https://blog.devgenius.io/embedded-youtube-videos-in-swiftui-900d3a0e80d4